# Req logging level

Tags: grails, logging

I just started on a big grails project and I noticed that in the console some of the logger messages start with `REQ`. Im not sure what generates these messages, and Im not sure what exactly it means. Here are some sample messages -

```
REQ 1E5BC3B3CF87EF159646D1ACDA534F79 - /notification/count
REQ 1E5BC3B3CF87EF159646D1ACDA534F79 - /userSetting/allRememberPage
REQ 1E5BC3B3CF87EF159646D1ACDA534F79 - /userSetting/email
```

My guess is that `REQ` means request, and the hex number after it is some sort of user ID, but Im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use grep or another search tool to do a case-sensitive search for REQ in your project and the plugins directory. That's unlikely to show up often, so you should quickly find it. It's likely something another developer added, or maybe from a plugin.